# How to start an activity from BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() method when app is in background?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I want to start an activity from the `onReceive()` method of the BroadcastReceiver. This is the code i am using:

```
class TimeReminderReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
     override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
         println("RECEIVED")

         val i = Intent(p0!!, TimeReminderActivity::class.java)
         i.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
         p0.startActivity(i)
     }
}
```

There are many answers for this question in stackoverflow, i tried all of it and none of it is working for me. The app just prints  `RECEIVED` and stays there. Nothing shows at the logcat, no exception, nothing. I have added the receiver in the mainfest also.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".receivers_and_activities.TimeReminderReceiver" />
```

Whats the problem with this code?

**EDIT:**

Code that calls the broadcast:

```
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, TimeReminderReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this@MainActivity, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
val am = this@MainActivity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
```

Comment: Is your App is in Foreground? or Background? and on which API level you're testing it?

Comment: when I receive the broadcast, my app is in background. I am testing on API level 29. My project's sdk version is also 29.

Comment: @MuhammadFarhan i just found out that when the app is in foreground while receiving the broadcast, activity opens fine.

Comment: @eegooDeveloper calling this broadcast form where can u show code?

Comment: @kdblue i got that code from [Schedule repeating alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you commented out you are trying to launch an Activity when your App is in **Background** on **Android 10 (API level 29)**.

From Android (API level 29) they put some restrictions to open an Activity when your App is in Background.

> Android 10 (API level 29) and higher place restrictions on when apps
>   can start activities when the app is running in the background.

You can find out here [Restrictions on starting activities from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).

They have also mentioned that

> In nearly all cases, apps that are in the background should display
>   time-sensitive notifications to provide urgent information to the user
>   instead of directly starting an activity. Examples of when to use such
>   notifications include handling an incoming phone call or an active
>   alarm clock.

So to overcome this behavior instead of calling your App when it is in the background you should show **high-priority notification** with a **full-screen intent**.

For more information on High-Priority Notification and Full-Screen Intent, you can check it here [Display time-sensitive notifications](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive)